# Can i control access end point When some table data changed In Mysql Semisynchronous Replication

Tags: mysql-5.7, master-slave-replication

I'm trying to set up One master Multi slave in MySQL 5.7

My architecture is like this.

```
Master - First slave(sync)
Second slave, Third slave, Fourth slave, Fifth slave(async)
```

My question is, If `a`Table data is changed Then application must access First slave. Until all slave is synchronized.

Because another slave data is not realtime sync...

Do you know this function supports library or tools?
If you have an other idea, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

"Semisync" implies

- One of the slaves has received the DML and stored it safely (in the relay log).
- That slave has *not necessarily* applied the statement.
- If the Master crashes, then at least one slave has *every* transaction that was `COMMITted` on the Master.
- Once you find that Slave, you could promote it to Master with confidence.